# django south arranging columns

Tags: django-south

I'm using South to handle migrations for my application. Everything is working fine however I notice that when I add a new column, it's at the end. Is there a way to tell south to put the column in a particular location?

Right now I'm doing this manually and it seems fairly cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all DB engines support adding a column in the middle of a table, so I guess South decided to leave this option out and just add the new columns at the end. This should not have any affect on your application or it's performance so their decision is logical and acceptable.

In case you want your table to look "ordered" you need to go the extra mile yourself. If you're using PostgreSQL you can check their "hack" for positioning columns in the middle [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Alter_column_position), under "*Add columns and move data*". For MySQL you can edit the migration SQL file adding `AFTER someExistingColumn` to the `ALTER` script.

```
ALTER TABLE someTable ADD newColumn VARCHAR(255) AFTER someExistingColumn
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly how I'm doing it now.